# Needs to identify cause of high load average

Tags: linux, ubuntu, load-average, iostat

I see high kB_read in iostat output. right now, load average of the system is very high. Is it io bound high load?

[image]

Comment: Post text, not image

Comment: Do the read/write benchmarking for host to check if you choose correct disks for your workload.